# GULP - vinyl-ftp doesn't upload subfolders

Tags: javascript, gulp, vinyl-ftp

I try to make a deploy-task in my gulpfile.

```
/** Configuration **/
var user = '12345';  
var password = 'mypwd';  
var host = 'example.com';  
var port = 21;  
var localFilesGlob = [
'build/*', 
'php/*'];  
var remoteFolder = '/gulptest'

function getFtpConnection() {  
    return ftp.create({
        host: host,
        port: port,
        user: user,
        password: password,
        parallel: 5
    });
}

gulp.task('deploy', function() {
    var conn = getFtpConnection();  
    return gulp.src(localFilesGlob, { base: '.', buffer: false })
    .pipe(conn.newer(remoteFolder)) 
    .pipe(conn.dest(remoteFolder));
});
```

but gulp somehow doesn't upload the subfolders which are in `php/`

there is another issue, too .. sometimes gulp thows me an error

> Error: Timeout while connecting to server
>       at null._onTimeout (E:\XAMPP\htdocs\test\node_modules\vinyl-ftp\node_modules\ftp\lib\connection.js:304:24)
>       at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)

can someone tell me, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `php/**` instead of `php/*`.

Comment: Works :) .. thank you! :)